# Silly space in Codeigniter views blowing up my mind

Tags: html, codeigniter, view, space

I'm working in the Codeigniter. Don't know a strange extra space is showing up in my all HTML views. I've tried and even remove whole HTML from the view but still the space at the beginning is showing up. Does anyone got the clue? [Please check in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86oc2.png)

Comment: Search all your files for a tab or spaces before opening php tag (configuration files, controller, loaded models, everything !)

Comment: I'm not using the models, and controllers and just calling the views like this.  $this->load->view('page_name', $data); Which config file, do I need to look?

Comment: All the files file you've edited. (config/config.php, config/database.php, your controller, your views maybe, ...)